# Why phantomjs does not load HTML page with <script type="module">?

Tags: javascript, phantomjs

I have a page (https://example.com/obj_renderer) that contains something like this:

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="module" src="https://example.com/myobjt.js"></script>
        <script type="module">
            MY_OBJ.execute();
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="render_container"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

This page runs at same site (example.com) from what I'm importing.
This works fine on browser, but when I open this page (https://example.com/obj_renderer) on phantomjs to print it returns blank screen.

If I replace with `<script>document.write('test')</script>` works fine, the image is generated, so is not and issue with the phantomjs screenshot code.

I can't use `require()` instead of modules, since it does not work either.
Does phantomjs support it? Or could be an issue on my imported js (can't share the code here)?

Comment: phantomjs development [was suspended in 2018](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/issues/15344), not long after modules became a thing. If you're waiting for it to be updated, you may be waiting for a while. You may want to switch to another platform, like puppeteer.